# got IOException in android?

Tags: java, android, exception, ioexception

```
03-18 19:31:55.883: VERBOSE/HttpSample_View(298): java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
03-18 19:31:55.883: VERBOSE/HttpSample_View(298): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:585 0xaf586674:0x00000000)
```

why i got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the client doesn't talk (provide) SSL on the adressed port.

Comment: but it works some time not working some other time.what can i do for that?

Comment: Does it happen on a real phone or in emulator?

Comment: Praveen, I suggest you edit your question and provide a lot more details of the environment and the actual problems. Otherwise I doubt that you will get more helpful answers. At least you should name the communication partners and show which part of the communication fails.

Comment: i tried to load image's url to an Imageview using BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_url.openConnection.getInputStream); method. here i got the exception.